# Run onChangeText doesnt update correctly TextInput value

Tags: react-native

I'm creating my own searchbar in react-native, so I want to allow user clear the text input. To achieve this I'm using `useState` to track when the text input `value` is empty or not. I'm executing `onStateChange('')` to clean the text input `value`, the problem is if I access to `value` this show the value before `onStateChange('')` not empty string `''`.

e.g. If I type `react` on input and after that execute `onStateChange('')` I expect the input `value` property to be empty, but it is not, `value` contains `react` yet, If I press other key the value is `''` and not the current one. i.e. it is not saving the last value entered but the previus one.

#### SearchBar Usage

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

function SearchBar(props) {
  const {
    onChangeText,
    value = '',
    ...textInputProps
  } = props;
  // Access to native input
  const textInputRef = React.createRef();
  // Track if text input is empty according `value` prop
  const [isEmpty, setIsEmpty] = useState(value ? value === '' : true);

  const clear = () => {
    // Clear the input value with native text input ref
    textInputRef.current?.clear();
    // Update the text input `value` property to `''` i.e. set to empty, 
    if (onChangeText) onChangeText('');
    // this is where the problem lies, because If I check the input text `value` property, this show the previus one, not the current one.
    console.log(value);
  };

  const handleOnChangeText = (text) => {
    if (onChangeText) onChangeText(text);
    // track if text input `value` property is empty
    setIsEmpty(text === '');
  };

  // Render close icon and listen `onPress` event to clear the text input
  const renderCloseIcon = (iconProps) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={clear}>
      <View>
        <Icon {...iconProps} name="close" pack="material" />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={focus}>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          {...textInputProps}
          onFocus={handleOnFocus}
          onBlur={handleOnBlur}
          onChangeText={handleOnChangeText}
          ref={textInputRef}
        />
        // helper function to render a component with props pased to it
        <FalsyFC
          style={{ paddingHorizontal: 8 }}
          // If text input `value` is `isEmpty` show the `x` icon   
          component={!isEmpty ? renderCloseIcon : undefined}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

#### SearchBar Usage

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const updateSearch = (query: string) => {
    setSearch(query);
  };

  return (
    <SearchBar
      onChangeText={updateSearch}
      value={search}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `value` prop in the `TextInput` (see React Native doc for [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)).

In your case you would set your `value` variable from the props object you pass to the `SearchBar` functional component:

```
    <TextInput
      {...textInputProps}
      onFocus={handleOnFocus}
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      onChangeText={handleOnChangeText}
      ref={textInputRef}
      // add the line below
      value={value}
    />
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect, the value is the same as before the last one typed.

Answer (score 0):

Every state changes are asynchronous even Hooks. With useState() you can't define a callback function even onStateChange() is not called. In your case, you should use the function useEffect().

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
  //Write your callback code here
  //copy-paste what you wrote on function onStateChange()
  }, [search]);
  const updateSearch = (query: string) => {
    setSearch(query);
  };

  return (
    <SearchBar
      onChangeText={updateSearch}
      value={search}
    />
  )
}
```

Here is a link that should help you :

[https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/#:~:text=callback%20is%20the%20callback%20function,dependencies%20have%20changed%20between%20renderings](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/#:%7E:text=callback%20is%20the%20callback%20function,dependencies%20have%20changed%20between%20renderings).

Comment: I don't understand your answer, you are running `useEffect` on `SomeComponent`, that is where I'm running `SearchBar`. When you say: write your `callback code` inside `useEffect`, you are referring to `updateSearch`? because I see that in your answer you are placing it outside of `useEffect`, if on the contrary you mean to place the `useEffect` in the `SearchBar` code I would like you to clarify your answer.